# How can I replace backslash characters in a Java String

Tags: java, string

How can I replace parts of a String. Specifically `\` with `/` in Java. I tried using `string.replace("". "")`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Please read the javadoc of methods you use before using them.

Comment: it was the method I was referring to.. not the way I used it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered millions on time:

```
myString.replace("\\", "/")
```

Probably your confusion comes from the fact that you have to escape it.

Comment: You'd need to escape the backslash, since this is a String.

Comment: Thanks, I realized right after writing it

Comment: @AntonioMG - I was under the impression it should be `myString.replace("\\\\", "/")`? I have never seen compile errors using `"\\"`, but I have seen runtime errors when only using `"\\"` - Any chance somebody could explain when you can only use 2 vs when you have to use 4?

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to replace characters you can do it with `replace(char toReplace, char replacement)` like

  ```
  yourString = yourString.replace('\\', '/');// since \ is special character in Java 
  //to create its literal you need to write it with another \ before '\\'
  ```
- If you need to replace substrings use `replace(String yourSubstring, String replacement)` (note that this will use regex mechanism but will escape regex meta characters so for replacing single characters `replace(char1, char2)` is faster).
- If you want to replace few substrings that are not the same, but can be described with regular expression you can use `replaceAll(regex, replacement)` or `replaceFirst(regex, replacement)`